# Creating a GUI Countdown Timer Unity5

Tags: gui, unity, timer

This was originally posted as a follow-up comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714357/guitext-in-unity-5-need-an-alternative , but I'm asking it here as a dedicated question as per the community's recommendation.

**What I'm trying to do:** display GUI Text on screen as a countdown timer that counts down in real time

**What I've done so far:**

- watched YouTube tutorial:  "Unity Scripting Tutorial 7 - A Countdown Timer" by VR Enthusiast.[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeLLi4icfWs)
- GameObject --> UI --> Text --> renamed: TimerText
- Wrote the Timer script in C#

  ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   using System.Collections;

   public class Timer : MonoBehaviour

  public float seconds = 59;
  public float minutes = 0;

  void Update() {

      if (seconds <= 0) {

          seconds = 59;
          if (minutes > 1) {

              minutes--;

          } else {

              minutes = 0;
              seconds = 0;
              GameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");

          }

      } else {

          seconds -= Time.deltaTime;

      }

      if(Mathf.Round(seconds) <= 9) {

          GameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + seconds.ToString("f0");

      } else {

          GameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = minutes.ToString("f0") + ":" + seconds.ToString("f0");

      }

  }
  ```

  }
- placed the TimerText object in the GUI Text object reference

Then I got this error:

```
"MissingComponentException: There is no 'GUIText' attached to the "TimerText" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a GUIText to the game object "TimerText". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. Timer.Update () (at Assets/Timer.cs:40)"
```

I essentially placed The object GUI Text object itself (TimerText) as its own scripting reference in Unity's Inspector. Not sure where to go from here. Any advice on what I can do next? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to access the GUIText.

One way would be a public reference in the class or, like you already did, *GetComponent*.

The advantage of using a public reference is, that you do not have to attach the timer on the **GameObject** with the **GUIText** component. You just declare the variable like so:

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUIText timerText;

    ...
}
```

You can then replace all GetComponent calls with timerText. To set this variable, simply drag and drop the GameObject that contains the GUIText component onto the **Timer Text** field in the Editor.

The *GetComponent* method, requires you, that the **Timer** script is attached to the same **GameObject** that contains the **GUIText**, *or* it is called on a **GameObject** on which has **GUIText** attached. 
It is also recommended, to use *GetComponent* just once, in the *Start* function of your **Timer** class, and store it in a variable.

Comment: @ user000user : Thanks for the advice, but I'm still unable to display the countdown timer on screen. Every time I try to add the "GUI Text" in the public field in Unity's inspector, it won't allow it (GameObject --> UI --> Text). If I try to add it via AddComponent--> GUIText, it accepts it as a component...but won't display on screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a GameObject **GO**, click 'Add Component' -> Rendering -> GUIText. Now select your GameObject with the _Timer_ component and drag **GO** on the _'Timer Text'_ field. Unity detects the GUIText component on **GO** and will automatically pass it to _'Timer Text'_.